# WSO2 SSO and Multitenancy Problems

Tags: single-sign-on, identity, wso2

I am evaluating SSO with WSO2 Identity Server. I ran into following problem/scenario. I have one or several SSO ServiceProvider (aka websites). I have one WSO2 Identity Server. I want commercial customers to be able to manage their users themself, and that users to be able to login into the same ServiceProviders. 
I set up a Service provider, I can login into it, with users defined in wso2 itself. I set up a tenant. I added same issuer in the tenant and globally. I can generally login into the sso protected site with a global user. I can login with a tenant user, but:
When the request gets back, after the login, I see following error on screen (and in logs):

```
org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.agent.exception.SSOAgentException: Signature validation failed for SAML Response
    org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.agent.saml.SAML2SSOManager.validateSignature(SAML2SSOManager.java:467)
    org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.agent.saml.SAML2SSOManager.processSSOResponse(SAML2SSOManager.java:215)
    org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.agent.saml.SAML2SSOManager.processResponse(SAML2SSOManager.java:142)
    org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.agent.SSOAgentFilter.doFilter(SSOAgentFilter.java:87)
```

I see also a lot in the logs, ending with

```
16:45:39.399 [http-bio-8080-exec-1] WARN  o.a.x.s.signature.XMLSignature - Signature verification failed.
16:45:39.399 [http-bio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG o.o.xml.signature.SignatureValidator - Signature did not validate against the credential's key`
```

directly prior to the exception. If I simply hit F5, I am logged in and can use the site (meaning that my SSOAgentSesisonBean returns a valid subject).

If I try to logout from this session, I receive an error now on the opposite site, in the WSO2 IS:

```
TID: [0] [IS] [2014-05-05 16:38:54,589] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.saml.servlet.SAMLSSOProviderServlet} -  Query string : SAMLRequest=nZLBbsIwDIZfJcqdtkCRRkTLkBASEgNpbDvsFlpDA6nNEjNtb79Ax0AcOEzKIYp%2F%2B7c%2FZzD8qq34BOcNYSbbUSIFYEGlwU0mX18mrQc5zAde17azVzPa0IGf4eMAnkXIRK%2BaUCYPDhVpb7xCXYNXXKjl6GmmOlGi9o6YCrJSjEOiQc0nt4p571Uc056NBe8pKiKNxBU4oyMEVv007cZHhxCUYjrO5BZ3ZGlH5Yq2dqc3Vbmt1xZwbUjbra1WdVWVWhdB7f0BpuhZI2eyk7TTVtIL56Wdqm5fJZ2o3UvepZgTL3DhRmsGd6tL04vuGbQ%2Fdr0MaCyIhoUUb2d2YVD5S0qdvN01ofuAtPfgjlBkHsa%2BQBjE1%2FXO1echfzr%2BT3UxIVdrvi8%2FvpiytT5JFSAb%2FpZ5syRd1gYfm3tUwrm%2FpqO%2Ff7IMywx2UyzhK85%2FRTffJ%2F8B&SigAlg=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F09%2Fxmldsig%23rsa-sha1&Signature=A9nB2Mt6aK%2Be8jlOau4ERjw6C1FX3ZiO%2FOzZ77oWhkNalypG7OSTYk6dndt8j4BpAeSfYEfQAh8VBhygL%2BBmcY8RFb93HpB6UnYEdoO0sQy3dhg1iZYoLEMnwScv8odbA54nXdPFT%2B%2FbTBK4rFJ6GcCphKHP9wJcwIPF0KVjKHU%3D {org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.saml.servlet.SAMLSSOProviderServlet}
TID: [0] [IS] [2014-05-05 16:38:54,590] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.saml.util.SAMLSSOUtil} -  Request message <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><saml2p:LogoutRequest xmlns:saml2p="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol" Destination="https://xxx.c.anotheria.net:9443/samlsso" ID="jnkolokodbojlkaghdjmflenfioaljlhbmhhdaac" IssueInstant="2014-05-05T14:39:02.150Z" NotOnOrAfter="2014-05-05T14:44:02.150Z" Reason="Single Logout" Version="2.0"><saml2:Issuer xmlns:saml2="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">net.anotheria</saml2:Issuer><saml2:NameID xmlns:saml2="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion" Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:entity">xxxadmin@xxx.de</saml2:NameID><saml2p:SessionIndex/></saml2p:LogoutRequest> {org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.saml.util.SAMLSSOUtil}
TID: [0] [IS] [2014-05-05 16:38:54,595] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.saml.processors.LogoutRequestProcessor} -  Error Processing the Logout Request {org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.saml.processors.LogoutRequestProcessor}
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.saml.processors.LogoutRequestProcessor.process(LogoutRequestProcessor.java:116)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.saml.SAMLSSOService.validateSPInitSSORequest(SAMLSSOService.java:115)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.saml.servlet.SAMLSSOProviderServlet.handleSPInitSSO(SAMLSSOProviderServlet.java:236)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.saml.servlet.SAMLSSOProviderServlet.handleRequest(SAMLSSOProviderServlet.java:132)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.saml.servlet.SAMLSSOProviderServlet.doGet(SAMLSSOProviderServlet.java:75)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:735)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.helper.ContextPathServletAdaptor.service(ContextPathServletAdaptor.java:37)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ServletRegistration.service(ServletRegistration.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.processAlias(ProxyServlet.java:128)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.service(ProxyServlet.java:60)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.servlet.DelegationServlet.service(DelegationServlet.java:68)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.filter.CharacterSetFilter.doFilter(CharacterSetFilter.java:61)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.continueInvocation(CompositeValve.java:178)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonTomcatValve$1.invoke(CarbonTomcatValve.java:47)
    at org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.TenantLazyLoaderValve.invoke(TenantLazyLoaderValve.java:56)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.TomcatValveContainer.invokeValves(TomcatValveContainer.java:47)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValve.java:141)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:156)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1653)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
TID: [0] [IS] [2014-05-05 16:38:54,596] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.saml.servlet.SAMLSSOProviderServlet} -  Error when processing the authentication request! {org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.saml.servlet.SAMLSSOProviderServlet}
org.wso2.carbon.identity.base.IdentityException: Error Processing the Logout Request
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.saml.processors.LogoutRequestProcessor.process(LogoutRequestProcessor.java:206)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.saml.SAMLSSOService.validateSPInitSSORequest(SAMLSSOService.java:115)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.saml.servlet.SAMLSSOProviderServlet.handleSPInitSSO(SAMLSSOProviderServlet.java:236)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.saml.servlet.SAMLSSOProviderServlet.handleRequest(SAMLSSOProviderServlet.java:132)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.saml.servlet.SAMLSSOProviderServlet.doGet(SAMLSSOProviderServlet.java:75)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:735)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.helper.ContextPathServletAdaptor.service(ContextPathServletAdaptor.java:37)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ServletRegistration.service(ServletRegistration.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.processAlias(ProxyServlet.java:128)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.service(ProxyServlet.java:60)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.servlet.DelegationServlet.service(DelegationServlet.java:68)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.filter.CharacterSetFilter.doFilter(CharacterSetFilter.java:61)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.continueInvocation(CompositeValve.java:178)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonTomcatValve$1.invoke(CarbonTomcatValve.java:47)
    at org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.TenantLazyLoaderValve.invoke(TenantLazyLoaderValve.java:56)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.TomcatValveContainer.invokeValves(TomcatValveContainer.java:47)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValve.java:141)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:156)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1653)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.saml.processors.LogoutRequestProcessor.process(LogoutRequestProcessor.java:116)
    ... 38 more
```

I can login and logout with globalusers without any problems.
I assume that the error is on the first-login-return side, but I can't imagine which.

Answer (score 1):

First check whether you can login to WSO2 IS with the tenant user you created.

If you created a tenant, then register the SPs in the tenant, then you should be able to login to web sites with WSO2 Identity Server as IDP, with the tenant users.

With the message you have seen, this seems to be an error in authentication. Not specific to SSO.

Thanks,
Pushpalanka

Comment: Thank you Pushpalanka, I adjusted the roles and SSO providers, and it works a little bit more now ;-) See the changed description.